# tar:invalid magic, tar:short read

Tags: linux, termux

I enter this command
su -c busybox tar -xvf /storage/emulated/0/Download/andrax.r5-build5.tar.xz -C /data/data/com.thecrackertechnology.andrax/ANDRAX/

and such an error appears
tar:invalid magic
tar:short read

Comment: Does [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302192/how-to-solve-tar-invalid-magic-error-on-linux-alpine) help?  Your tar file might be corrupted.

Answer (score 5):

Automatic detection of the compression format is a GNU feature.

For BusyBox and other `tar`s, specify the format explicitly (`busybox tar --help`):

```
    -Z      (De)compress using compress
    -z      (De)compress using gzip
    -J      (De)compress using xz
    -j      (De)compress using bzip2
    -a      (De)compress using lzma
```

In your case:

```
busybox tar -xJvf file.tar.xz
```

(note that if passing it to `su -c`, the whole command needs to be quoted to be passed as a single argument)